# Recording an ultralight plane in flight

Tags: plane, recording

Hi. I have the opportunity to record and ultralight plane in flight.
I have a Sanken css 5, but i d like to know what do you think about wind protection.
The wind up there ill be really strong, so is it possible to make a good recording?What should i use to protect the mic? Do you have any experience in a similar situation?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Definitely use a zeppelin with a furry cover and mount the zep with foam underneath to decouple it from the vibrations of the engine.

In addition, I'd suggest pointing the mic backwards and building some sort of makeshift windshield/guard around the rear end of the zeppelin to further shelter it from the wind. It's amazing what you can build with some cardboard and a ton of gaffers tape. I've recorded car exteriors this way with good results.

Good luck...sounds like fun.

Answer (score 0):

A guy at Dane Tracks showed me a zeppelin he uses for on board vehicle recordings.  It has a crazy cork screw shape designed to let the wind pass over as silently as possible.  Its not furry at all.  Not sure what it was called, but he swears by it.

dr

Comment: I'd love to hear more about this zeppelin...was it a custom design?

Comment: I suspect David is referring to the DPA zeppelin that is no longer made.  That is the only one I can think of with a crazy shape like that.  http://mixonline.com/mag/audio_snapshot_product_reviews_24/

Comment: As yes the short-lived windpac...I can't imagine that it would be that effective at recording car exteriors.

Comment: Yes, sepulchra.  That looks like the one.  Its been a few years since i saw it, but the guy swore by it, and was very experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a few skydives out of a microlight, and I don't recall the wind being very strong as it doesn't go too fast. You should be more than fine using a Zeppelin/Blimp. You sit behind the pilot and you probably won't be aiming the mic in front so you should have some added wind protection from him.

**be super careful**

The prop is right behind you, and very close. Not all microlights have a protective grill, my friend lost his hand skydiving out of one - sliced his hand right off. Just be aware of your space at all times, don't just point the mic without taking care of where it is!

Comment: That's gotta hurt